# open each Bootstrap 3 Modal one after another and not opening all together

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have unlimited modals starting from modal_0.

What I need is when closing one modal another is opened and not all opening together as in following code.

So how can it be solved?

```
$("#modal_0").on('hidden.bs.modal',function () {
  for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#modal_"+i).modal({toggle: true, backdrop: 'static',keyboard:false,show:true});
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made you an example with 3 modals using a **recursive mechanism**, hope this helps you:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    startRecursiveModalOpening(0);
});

function startRecursiveModalOpening(modalID)
{
    var modalOptions = {
        toggle: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: true
    };

    // Register listener for modal hidden event one time.

    $("#modal_" + modalID)
        .modal(modalOptions)
        .one("hidden.bs.modal", function()
        {
            var nextModal = $("#modal_" + (modalID + 1));
            
            if (nextModal.length > 0)
                startRecursiveModalOpening(modalID + 1);
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Modal 0 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        MODAL 0
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">BODY</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        MODAL 1
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">BODY</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        MODAL 2
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">BODY</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the modal's `id` has `'modal_' + sequence` as pattern, and that  the modals should be displayed based on this sequence:

> `modal_0` ➝ `modal_1` ➝ `modal_2` ➝ and so on...

Then you could try attaching the event handler like this:

```js
$('[id^="modal_"]').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  var nextId = parseInt(this.id.substring(6)) + 1;
  $("#modal_"+ nextId).modal({
    toggle: true, 
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard:false,
    show:true
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_0">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="modal_0" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 0</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_1" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_2" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_3" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_4" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 4</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_5" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 5</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: may I ask what is meam this part `substring(6)` ?